# React : state is empty when trying to get it from child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I got two react components. The first component is managing a list of the second component after making a call to my api and I tried to put a delete button to remove one component from the list.

I got a weird behavior : when I click on the remove document button the document is set to an empty array. And I got a log of an empty array for the documents.

Parent component :

```
export const DocumentEnvelope: React.FC<DocumentEnvelopeProps> = (props) => {
    const [documents, setDocuments] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        setDocuments([]);
        axios.get("/myurl").then(response => {
            response.data.forEach(document => {
                setDocuments((doc) => [...doc, <Document name={document.name} removeDocument={removeDocument}/>]);});
        });
    }, []);

    const removeDocument = (name) => {
        console.log(documents);
        setDocuments(documents.filter(item => item.name !== name));
    };

    return (
        <>
            {documents}
        </>
    );
};
```

Child component :

```
interface DocumentProps {
    removeDocument,
    name: string
}

export const Document: React.FC<DocumentProps> = (props) => {

    return (
        <div>
            My document
            <button onClick={() => props.removeDocument(props.name)}>
                Remove document
            </button>
        </div>
    );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<Document name=document.name removeDocument={removeDocument}/>
```

This part is missing curly braces around `document.name`, consider using a different variable name as `document` is used to refer to the html document in javascript. I can also recommend storing the data in the state but not the components themselves.

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake on simplifying the code I am using. But this is not the cause of the problem

Answer (score 1):

You're filtering on the `documents` array as if it consisted of `document` objects. But you have set the `documents` array to list of `Document` React Elements.

Let your `documents` array consist pure JS objects i.e. a `document` as you're getting it from response instead of React elements. Use `map` in JSX to loop over `documents` and return `<Document.../>` elements.

I mean like the following :-

```
export const DocumentEnvelope: React.FC<DocumentEnvelopeProps> = (props) => {
    const [documents, setDocuments] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get("/myurl").then(response => {
            setDocuments(response.data);
    }, []);

    const removeDocument = (name) => {
        setDocuments(documents.filter(document => document.name !== name));
    };

    return (
        <>
            {documents.map((document)=>
           <Document name={document.name} removeDocument={removeDocument}/>
)}
        </>
    );
};
```